# Does the condition variable blocks the rest of the execution ? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

If I have this code

```
behavior.initialize();
management.initialize();
```

and in behavior.initialize() we use a condition variable (we are waiting a condition to happen to continue the initialization),

Are we going to be stuck in the behavior initialization until the condition becomes true and the initialization finish, or we are going to continue to the management initialization and the behavior initialization will be in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 1):

if this method call here

```
behavior.initialize();
```

do a return then

```
management.initialize();
```

is executed...

Answer (score 1):

The instructions run one after the other. So if your waiting until a condition is true, it'll wait there. Everything below that will stand still.

The only counteract is to use multiple threads; put `behavior.initialize()` to one thread and `management.initialize();` to the other so that behavior will wait until the condition is true; the management will run freely. If the two functions are set sequentially, the second function will wait until the first function finishes.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how those two functions spawn threads or use condition variables, the thread that calls the two methods:

```
behavior.initialize();
management.initialize();
```

does that sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

A condition variable will put your whole thread to sleep until some other thread will wake it up via condition variable's method `notify_one` or `notify_all`. Since your thread is fast asleep, the answer to your question is clear:  You are going to be "stuck in the behavior initialization until the condition becomes true". The idea is that if one thread cannot go on until some other thread is ready to provide some important information, this first  thread goes to sleep and does not use up the CPU clocks. The logic is as if instead of a condition variable you had

```
while(!the_other_thread_is_ready())
  continue;
```

but without doing all these checks. With a conditon variable you rely on the other thread to wake your thread up instead (and the trick is to make sure the signal to wake up will not be missed, but it's another story).